# NativeScriptException failed to find module

Tags: nativescript

The following is the my application  structure. I am getting an error "NativeScriptException failed to find module ", "../../shared/view-models/user-view-model", relative to ./shared/view-models/

Please[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AaibT.jpg) find the screenshot of the application.

Comment: Looking at the screenshot I would suggest to try to rename `user-view-model` file to `user-view-model.js`

Comment: Did you find the solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

You require a wrong path. Replace by this:

```
var UserViewModel = require("../shared/viewmodels/user-view-model");
```

P/s: And also, the folder under `shared`is "viewmodels", not "view-models"